# Is center of connected nilpotent Lie group lattice hereditary?

Tags: lie-groups, nilpotent-groups

This might be a stupid question, but I couldn't find a reference/explanation.

Let $G$ be a connected nilpotent Lie group, and $\Gamma$ a lattice in it.
If $Z$ is the center of $G$, is it true that $\Gamma \cap Z(G)$ is always a lattice in $Z(G)$? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, it's a theorem which is certainly in Raghunathan's book. (If stated only for simply connected nilpotent Lie groups, the case of general connected nilpotent Lie groups follows easily.)

Comment: Thanks! May you please explain how it follows?

Comment: You need to know that in every connected nilpotent Lie group, the center is connected. If you have a connected nilpotent Lie group, it has the form $G/L$ with $G$ simply connected and $L$ discrete central. Its center has the form $Z/L$ with $Z$ connected, and $Z$ is also the center of $G$. If $M/L$ is a lattice in $G/L$, then $M$ is a lattice in $G$, so $M\cap Z$ is a lattice in $L$ (by the simply connected case), and hence $M/L$ is a lattice in $Z/L$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry to be pedantic, but I have one step to clarify. You said that $Z(G/L) = Z(G)/L$: why? This is generally not true for $L \unlhd G$, for otherwise, we would always have trivial $Z(G/Z(G))$. And this is not the case for say, the dim-3 heisenberg group, where $Z(H_3(\mathbb{R})/Z(H_3(\mathbb{R})) = Z(\mathbb{R^2}) = \mathbb{R}^2$.
And in the case when $G$ and $L$ are both discrete (think of finite groups), there are still may examples like that

Comment: As I said, it's a consequence of the fact that the center of $G$ and $G/L$ are both connected (and that $L$ is discrete).

Comment: Is it true that for a connected Lie group $G$, and a normal **discrete** $L \unlhd Z(G)$ such that $G/L$ connected, it is guaranteed that $Z(G/L) = Z(G)/L$? And if $L$ is not discrete, then this is not guaranteed? In the example I gave above, we have all the conditions stated here satisfied, except that $L$ is also connected

Comment: Yes, it is true (you can omit "such that $G/L$ is connected" since it is automatic). Indeed, in a connected Lie group $G$, the center of $G$ is also the kernel of the adjoint representation of $G$ on its Lie algebra. This is therefore not changed under coverings. (And of course you need $L$ discrete.)